# How to create a txt with file names and save it to same folder with Automator on OSX?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, automator

I want to make a .txt file inside the same folder that contains all the filenames of said folder.

How can i do that?

Thanks.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can create an Automator Workflow like this as a Service, so that all you have to do is right click the folder, click the service and this text file will appear in the folder, with the name of the folder.

[image: Get Contents of Folder as Text Service Workflow]

Comment: That´s what i wanna do, but instead of a .txt file with the name of the folder i want that file to contain all the filenames of the files inside this folder.

Comment: Ok great. That's what the above does. It's puts the names of the folder contents in a text file and in that folder.

Comment: Yeah it works, but is there a way to create the "Get Names of Finder Items" action instead of using the one from Automated Workflows?, because it keeps asking me to register and it only lists 5 items.

Comment: No. You will have to use applescripting for that. The **Get Names of Finder Items** and the other 30 actions that come with that is well worth it as I use them all the time and it solved many workflows that I was trying to create.

Comment: Another question, i got it working, and i'm trying to add a keyboard shortcut to the service but it doesn't work. How can i accomplish this?. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in terminal by using

```
ls {DIR} >> {FILE}
```

for example if i wanted to write a file called 'ls.txt' of all the files on the desktop i could use

```
ls /Users/corvinmcpherson/Desktop/ >> /Users/corvinmcpherson/Desktop/ls.txt
```

you can also create one using automator like this:
[image]